# How to sort a DataGridView column that is has a DateTime Value, but is displayed as a String?

Tags: c#, datagridview

i have in my program a datagriview,i want to order columns by data,i use:

```
dataGridView1.Columns["Date"].ValueType = typeof(DateTime);
```

but when i click on Date column,it's didn't sort correctly.

my date format is: 23-12-1997

is incorrect write format of date?

Comment: can you post your binding code..datagridview has a capability to order columns..

Comment: How did it sort? Numericall, alphabetically?

Comment: What have you stored as the actual values? Are they actually DateTime? Aso: is this data-binding? Or explicit values?

Comment: no databindings,is only value. i sett cells by :dataGridView1.Columns["Date"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "{0:ddd'-'MM'-'yyyy}";

Answer (score 4):

Your cell Format should be:

```
dataGridView1.Columns["Date"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd-MM-yyyy";
```

Generally, this format will not affect sorting of this column if ValueType is DateTime. I suspect that you put a String value into this column, instead of a DateTime value.

An example:

```
            DataTable t = new DataTable();
            DataColumn c1 = new DataColumn("Name", typeof(String));
            DataColumn c2 = new DataColumn("Date", typeof(DateTime));
            t.Columns.Add(c1);
            t.Columns.Add(c2);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                t.Rows.Add(new object[] {i.ToString(), DateTime.Now.AddHours(i * 2) });
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = t;
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "HH MM/dd/yyyy";
```

Comment: didn't works.sorting in not correct.Make me crazy this problem.

Comment: Please post your code regarding putting data into your data grid view.

Comment: `ds = xmlDatadoc.DataSet;
 dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.DefaultViewManager;
 dataGridView1.DataMember = "Comp";
 dataGridView1.Columns["Data"].ValueType = typeof(DateTime);
 dataGridView1.Columns["Data"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd-MM-yyyy"; `

Comment: what's the data type of "Data" field in table "Comp" of ds DataSet? Is it a DateTime value or String value?

Comment: You should convert that string into DateTime before put it to DataTable.

Comment: Don't see extension `DefaultCellStyle` for GridView

Answer (score 1):

I did a lot of looking and then used something really easy.  I added a hidden column, and put in a string date in the following format:
File.GetLastWriteTime(fl).ToString("yyyyMMddhhmm") and sorted the hidden column.
While I am using a file time there is no reason that any date/time should not work.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this question researching a DataGridView sorting issue on date columns.  My case was slightly more complicated than the OP, so I am posting here in hopes it helps someone.

In my case, the DataSource of my DataGridView is set to a BindingSource object.  The DataSource of my BindingSource is a DataSet object.  I was able to fix the sorting issue without adding any code by changing a property in the DataSet designer.  I went to the Visual Studio designer and selected my DataSet.  In the properties window, I selected "Edit in DataSet Designer".  Then in the DataSet Designer, I selected my Column, and changed its DataType property to System.DateTime (it had previously been set to String).  Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

When you convert the DateTime value into a string when putting it into the datagrid you can specify a format... 2 of these are sortable.... the "u" option and the "s" option so all you need to do is something like this (startTime here is a DateTime object)....

```
DatadataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["TimeColumn"].Value = startTime.ToString("u");
```